# iOS 8 detect if SKSpriteNode is lit by SKLightNode

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, sklightnode

I have several sprite nodes in my scene that are casting shadows. I also have a sprite that is in one of the shadows. I want to be able to tell if the user moves a sprite out of a shadow into the light. Anyway to do this in swift? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly this functionality still isn't included in SpriteKit, however it is possible to implement a decent solution with some caveats.

To determine if a sprite casts a shadow, its [`shadowCastBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/1520325-shadowcastbitmask) property "is tested against the light's `categoryBitMask` property by performing a logical AND operation." SpriteKit appears to generate the exact same mask data for lighting and physics body calculations, based on the description given in the documentation for the [`shadowColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklightnode/1519844-shadowcolor) property defined on `SKLightNode`:

> When lighting is calculated, shadows are created as if a ray was cast
>   out from the light node's position. If a sprite casts a shadow, the
>   rays are blocked when they intersect with the sprite's physics body.
>   Otherwise, the sprite's texture is used to generate a mask, and any
>   pixel in the sprite node's texture that has an alpha value that is
>   nonzero blocks the light.

`SKPhysicsWorld` has a method, `enumerateBodies(alongRayStart:end:using:)`, for performing this kind of ray intersection test performantly. That means we can test if a sprite is shadowed by any sprite with a physics body. So we can write a method like this to extend `SKSpriteNode`:

```
func isLit(by light: SKLightNode) -> Bool {
    guard light.isEnabled else {
        return false
    }

    var shadowed = false

    scene?.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: light.position, end: position) { (body, _, _, stop) in
        if let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode, light.categoryBitMask & sprite.shadowCastBitMask != 0 {
            shadowed = true

            stop.pointee = true
        }
    }

    if shadowed {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

We can also retrieve which lights in the scene are lighting a particular sprite:

```
func lights(affecting sprite: SKSpriteNode) -> [SKLightNode] {
    let lights = sprite.scene?.children.flatMap { (node) -> SKLightNode? in
        node as? SKLightNode
    } ?? []

    return lights.filter { (light) -> Bool in
        sprite.isLit(by: light)
    }
}
```

It'd be great if SpriteKit provided a way to retrieve this information without coupling it to the physics API, or else requiring developers to roll their own ray cast implementations.